# How is data from the RAM fetched?

Tags: c, memory, x86, ram

In C each byte is individually addressable. Suppose an integer (say which uses 4 bytes) has an address `0xaddr` (which is 32 bits, assuming that we have a 32 bit processor with 32 bit address bus and 32 bit data bus) and suppose the value of the integer is `0x12345678`. Now if I am fetching this value from memory, how does the processor do this ? Does the processor place `0xaddr` (which is 32bit address) on the address lines and then fetch 8 bit data say `0x12`. And then processor will pace `0xaddr+1` on address lines and then fetch another 8 bit data `0x34` and so on for the 4 bytes of an integer? Or does the processor just place `0xaddr` and read the 4 bytes at once thus utilizing its full 32 bit data bus?

Comment: It depends. Which exact processor are you talking about? IIRC the 8086 had a 16bit data bus. Many newer models (Pentium and up) had a 64bit FSB.

Comment: @harold : can you plz let me know how its different for different processors. i am asking in general and not specific to any processor. how it will be done say fo 8086 which has 16 bit data bus, and how for 32 bit data bus and that for 64 ? thanks

Comment: it's a lot more complex than just a simple data bus, there's also cache

Comment: @KarolyHorvath : can you explain it a bit or point me to some article which can answer this question ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexer

Comment: @user1182722 there is no general answer.

Comment: can anyone let me know the ans in some detail, not able to get anything with one line ans's..if it is diff for diff processor's atleast let me know for x86 processors.

Comment: It's not even the same for all x86 processors. That's a huge family with wildly differing implementations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This is a well known article](http://lwn.net/Articles/250967/) by the GNU C library lead that describes memory access (particularly in x86 - current PC - systems).  It goes into far more detail than you can ever possibly need.

The entire article is spread across many parts:

1. [Introduction](http://lwn.net/Articles/250967/)
2. [CPU Caches](http://lwn.net/Articles/252125/)
3. [Virtual Memory](http://lwn.net/Articles/253361/)
4. [NUMA Support](http://lwn.net/Articles/254445/)
5. [Programmers](http://lwn.net/Articles/255364/)
6. [More Programmers](http://lwn.net/Articles/256433/)
7. [Performance Tools](http://lwn.net/Articles/257209/)
8. [Future](http://lwn.net/Articles/258154/)
9. [Appendices](http://lwn.net/Articles/258188/)

one thing i'd add to gbulmer's answer is that in many systems getting a stream of data is faster than you would expect from getting a single word.  in other words, selecting where you want to read from takes some time, but one you have that selected, reading from that point, and then the next 32 or 64 or whatever bits, and then the next... is faster than switching to some unconnected place and reading another value.

and what dominates modern programming is not the behaviour of fetching from memory on the motherboard, but whether the data are in a cpu cache.

Answer (score 4):

If you search the web for "Computer Architecture" you are likely to get some answers to your questions.

For your specific question, a 32bit computer, with a 32bit data and address bus, for a simple case, with no obfuscating hardware. It will read 32bits from a 32bit wide memory.

This is the sort of hardware which existed since the late 1970's as minicompters (e.g. DEC VAX), and still exists as microprocessors (x86, ARM, Cortex-A8, MIPS32) and inside some microcontrollers (e.g. ARM, Cortex-M3, PIC32, etc.).

The simplest case:
The address bus is a set of signals (wires) which carry address signals to memory, plus a few more signals to communicate whether memory is to be 'read from' or 'written to' (data direction), and whether the signals on the address and data direction wires are valid. In the case of your example, there might be 32 wires to carry the bit pattern of the address.

The data bus is a second set of wires which communicate the value to and from memory. Memory might assert a signal to say the data is valid, but it might just be fast enough that everything 'just works'.

When the processor puts the address on the address signals, says it wants to read from memory (data direction is 'read'), memory will retrieve the value stored at that address, and put it onto the data bus signals. The processor (after suitable delays and signals) will sample the data bus wires, and that is the value it uses.

The processor might read the whole 32bits, and extract a byte (if that is all the instruction requires) internally, or the external address bus may provide extra signals so that the external memory system can be built to provide the appropriate byte, double byte or quad byte values. For many years, versions of the ARM processor architecture could only read the whole 32bits, and smaller pieces, e,g, a byte, were extracted internally.

You can see an example of this sort of signal set at http://www.cpu-world.com/info/Pinouts/68000.html
That chip only has a 24bit address bus, and a 16bit data bus.
It has two signals (UDS and LDS) which signal whether the upper data signals are being used, the lower data signals, or both.

I found a reasonably detailed explanation at research.cs.tamu.edu/prism/lectures/mbsd/mbsd_l15.pdf
I found that by searching for "68000 memory bus cycle".

You might usefully look for MIPS, ARM, or x86 to see their bus cycle.